# JTableCellRenderer causing program to go black when minimized

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea, cellrenderer

I'm making a program that selects classes from a database via a jcombo box and then populates a time table with the class times.

I've used a custom cellrenderer that extends DefaultTableCellRenderer to text wrap the information and change the background of the cells.

It works but when i minimize the program it goes all black and if I double click I get a new JTextArea opening up on the timetable.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Here's the code i used and thanks for any help.

```
public class TimesTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

     private int minHeight = -1;
     private final JLabel label = new JLabel();
     private final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public TimesTableCellRenderer(){
        super();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setBackground(Color.cyan);

    }
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
     JTable table,
     Object value,
     boolean isSelected,
     boolean hasFocus,
     int row,
     int column) {

     Component c = null;
     if(value.toString()!=null){
             textArea.setText(value.toString());
             c = textArea;

             setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),130);

             setVisible(true);

     }else{
         System.out.println("error");
     }

     return c;
 }

}
```

and how they go on the timetable is like so

```
timeTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new TimesTableCellRenderer());
```

And this is an example of the code in action to see the error for yourselves although some things have been changed to make it easier to represent as it is part of a larger program.

```
public class NewTimeTable {

        JFrame s;

        public NewTimeTable(JFrame s){
            this.s=s;
            timetable();
            s.setVisible(true);
        }

        private JTable table;
        public JComboBox ModuleComboBox;
        public JTextArea DemonstratorTextArea;
        // public JTextPane DemonNamesTextPane;
        public JList demonNamesJList;
        public JPanel DemonNamesJPanel;

         JTable timeTable;
         JPanel frmMain;
        Container pane;
         static DefaultTableModel defaultTimeTableModule; // Table model
        JScrollPane scrollbarTT; // The scrollpane
         JPanel TimeTablePanel; // The panel

        public void timetable() {

        // creates the table container and where it is in the program
            defaultTimeTableModule= new DefaultTableModel();

            timeTable = new JTable(defaultTimeTableModule);

        scrollbarTT = new JScrollPane(timeTable);

        TimeTablePanel = new JPanel(null);
        TimeTablePanel.setBounds(554, 89, 715, 552);
        TimeTablePanel
                .setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Time Table"));
        TimeTablePanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        pane = s.getContentPane();
        pane.add(TimeTablePanel);
        TimeTablePanel.add(scrollbarTT);
        scrollbarTT.setBounds(22, 44, 668, 467);


        // gets the headers and stops them being reordered
        // allows for column and cell selections
        timeTable.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        timeTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        timeTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        timeTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        // Add headers
        String[] headers = { "Time", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri " };
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            defaultTimeTableModule.addColumn(headers[i]);
        }

        // Set background to white and draws in the grid
        timeTable.getParent().setBackground(timeTable.getBackground());
        timeTable.setRowHeight(35);
        defaultTimeTableModule.setColumnCount(6);
        defaultTimeTableModule.setRowCount(14);
        timeTable.setSize(135, 35);
        timeTable.setRowHeight(65);

        // add numbers to time column
        Integer count = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            count++;
            String time=null;

            if(count>12){
                time=count+".00 pm";
            }else{
                time=count+".00 am";
            }
            defaultTimeTableModule.setValueAt(time, i, 0);
        }
        timeTable.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);

    }

        public void addClassesToTimeTable(ArrayList<String> moduleInfo){
            int startRow = 0;
            int finishRow = 0;
            int column = 0;
            int c2 = 0;


                 String startTime=moduleInfo.get(0);
                 System.out.println(startTime);
                String finishTime=moduleInfo.get(1);
                 System.out.println(finishTime);

                 String day=moduleInfo.get(2);
                 System.out.println(day);

                double startTimeCell= Double.parseDouble(startTime);
                double finishTimeCell= Double.parseDouble(finishTime);

                    switch (day) {
                    case "Monday":
                    case "monday":
                        column=1;
                        break;
                    case "Tuesday":
                    case "tuesday":
                        column=2;
                        break;
                    case "Wednesday":
                    case "wednesday":
                        column=3;
                        break;
                    case "Thursday":
                    case "thursday":
                        column=4;
                        break;
                    case "Friday":
                    case "friday":
                        column=5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        //turn into pop up message
                        System.out.println("error in database on day");
                        break;
                    }

                    //count that tells you what row to place info on in start time
                    int count = 0;
                    int count2=0;
                    for (int loop = 9; loop <= startTimeCell; loop++) {
                        startRow=count;
                        count++;
                    }

                    for (int loop = 9; loop <= finishTimeCell; loop++) {
                        finishRow=count2;
                        count2++;
                    }

                    String name = moduleInfo.get(3);
                    defaultTimeTableModule.setValueAt(name, startRow, column);
                        timeTable.isCellEditable(finishRow, column);

                        timeTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).setCellRenderer(new TimesTableCellRenderer());
            timeTable.setAutoResizeMode(112);


        }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setBounds(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height - 30);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
     NewTimeTable s=new NewTimeTable(frame);

     ArrayList<String> a =  new ArrayList<>();
     a.add("9.00");
     a.add("10.00");
     a.add("Monday");
     a.add("name");

     s.addClassesToTimeTable(a);
      }

    }
```

EDIT:: Just noticed when I minimize the program and go to open it again i get a Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException and the cell render seems to be called again even though i haven't rerun the program.

Any thoughts on how to clear this up or why it's causing the program to go black?

Comment: setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),130); and              setVisible(true); aren't good code lines for quite intensive painting provided by renderer

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative? This is my first time using cell renderer so any help is appreciated

Comment: Generally, table rows have a fixed height, it's not really very easy to some multi line content within in.  One way is to wrap the text in HTML, which can out wrap the content, or use a tooltip

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the advice I've never used HTML but I'll google it and see if that works

Comment: That didn't seem to fix the problem or work for what i need so any other suggestions are welcome